# django about filter--I want to filter card, its age is over 30

Tags: django, filter

I want to filter card, its age is over 30.

```
    if user.age >= 30:
        card = models.MtomCard.objects.filter(age>30)
```

it doesn't work.. how do i fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`__gt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#gt) lookup:

```
card = models.MtomCard.objects.filter(age__gt=30)
```

Comment: Thank you very much